# How to overcome jealousy?

Tags: sin

Jealousy is considered a sin by many people along with other vices like greed, anger, arrogance, lust and delusion.

How do scriptures suggest to overcome jealousy (aka matsarya)?

Comment: Not scriptural, but generic. To "overcome" jealousy one must understand what exactly is jealousy. Jealousy is that sensation you get when your peers excel at something in which you have not excelled. This is very necessary evolutionary trait of staying well in a society. But it becomes a problem when this sensation is interpreted as a impulse to bring the other person down. If its used to elevate oneself its a virtue. You can't stop jealousy or you should not try to stop it. Ise it positively. The moment you use the same feeling to pull down someone or by being angry at them it becomes a sin.

Comment: This is same with all others like Kama, Krodha, Moha etc all of them are necessary. It becomes a problem when it malfunctions.

Comment: @MrGreenGold Thanks. I am not trying or had never tried to bring the other people down. That jealousy is not responding well though, it isn't making me content which I should assume a healthy virtue. I appreciate the sense of competitiveness, but lost content. I should not ask personal question here, so I am looking for what scriptures say about jealousy.

Comment: There are Karmas which develop good qualities and there are karmas which develop bad qualities. Eg, Nihswarth Daan or Selfless Donation reduces attachment to physical beings or wants. Mahabharat has many verses by Vidur and Bhishma where we talk about this, if I recall.

Comment: @SeverusSnape yes we can talk personally in comment section. The problem is you are trying to find content in material achievements. So you are not content. In a way it is healthy because if you are totally content you'll stop working. So till you are a perfect yogi, you need to work, and for working you need motive, so stop trying to achieve complete content in material achievements. Little healthy discontent is good IMHO. When the discontent becomes too much, to lower it to normal levels, understand that you are running excessively after material wealth and turn to God and spirituality. 

Comment: @SeverusSnape In other words be content with your discontent.

Comment: The farther you walk away from Mumbai and towards Delhi, the nearer you get to Delhi and the farther away from Mumbai. Walk to the Lord. Think of the Lord and jealousy will get farther away by itself naturally.

Comment: By start asking a series of "why?" to one-selves !!

Answer (score 2):

Mahabharat has many discussions where qualities due to karma are described. One can acquire good qualities willfully while avoid bad qualities by carefully choosing karma.

One can ditch bad qualities like Kaam (Want), Krodh (Anger) and Lobh (Greed) by following principle of Ahimsa or Avoiding Cruelty.

> [image]
> Sankshipt Mahabharat, Anushashan Parv, Page 708 (Geeta Press)

There are four ways to follow Ahimsa : By Man (Thought), by Vaani (Talk), by Karma (Actions) and by Avoiding consuming meat.

> [image]
>
> [image]
> Sankshipt Mahabharat, Anushashan Parv, Page 708 (Geeta Press)

One can reduce Matsyarta (Jealousy, Envy and Distrust) by following Satya (Truth). - Sankshipt Mahabharat, Shanti Parva

Comment: Can you quote the Matsarya portion alongwith/ instead of the Ahimsa portion? It’s a very nice Ahimsa quote btw

Comment: Jealousy, Eny, Greed not distrust cannot be contolled by satya as stated by @sbharti These are more sutle There different upasena of lord shri krishna todo that but i dont have scriptual reference. Like if one medidate on Lord Narashima and Utters Om kara with little extension of Maa kara will do again but This omkaara upasena is not for ladies.. and also those who are inherently evil even tough they are born poius family like duryoudhana (he is direct grandson lord veda vyasa/narayana) They cannot change anything instead if they do the upasena they can increase their bad qualities instead

Comment: @PrasannaR the statement is for Matsyarta. The English meaning is only for reference.