# Is there any scriptural opposition to humane animal slaughter?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, animals, cows, ahimsa

Note that I'm not talking about general ethics - I mean only from a religious scriptural perspective.

To give you full context on why I have this question:
Because cow slaughter is banned in many parts of India, it is not uncommon that some farmers let go of their aged cows onto the street. Here we see that in order to avoid slaughtering cows, we instigate starvation and abuse of the aged cows instead.

In such an instance, can jhaṭkā slaughter or a bolt pistol be considered a more dhārmic alternative?

Comment: Not for cows and cattle in general. Animal meat is generally frowned upon by scriptures. See this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48490/3881

Comment: @sbharti the OP is not talking about meat but killing animals to relieve them from suffering and hunger. 'Dayāvadha'.

Comment: @AravindSuresh yes you're right, my question concerns mercy killing of animals.